# correct way to make quaternion from local Euler angles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I am trying to lerp from rotation one to another. The another rotation is constitute using this

```
 Quaternion qNew = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(navigationCanvas.transform.rotation.x, navigationCanvas.transform.rotation.y, camRotationToWatch.transform.rotation.z));
```

The new rotation where I have to lerp is given above, Is this right? cause its is not doing what i meant
while i am lerping like this

```
 navigationCanvas.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(navigationCanvas.transform.rotation, qNew, Time.deltaTime * 2f);
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, [Unity uses quaternion to express rotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html) so as to prevent gimbal lock, thus `transform.rotation` **is already a quaternion** :

> ### Transform.rotation
>
> **Description**
>
> The rotation of the transform in world space stored as a Quaternion.

You have to use the [`eulerAngles` property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) instead :

```
Quaternion qNew = Quaternion.Euler( new Vector3(
    navigationCanvas.transform.eulerAngles.x,
    navigationCanvas.transform.eulerAngles.y,
    camRotationToWatch.transform.eulerAngles.z
));
```